# Dúvidas em um Select no SQL

Tags: sql

Galera estou com uma dúvida, estou querendo fazer uma consulta aonde se eu não selecionar um determinado campo gostaria que ele me retornasse todos

```
SELECT 
contapagar.*, 
profissional.profissional_descricao, 
paciente.paciente_descricao, 
status_parcela.statusparcela_descricao, 
forma_pagamento.formapgto_descricao, 
entidade.entidade_descricao, 
formapgto_bfinanceiro.formapgtobfin_descricao 
FROM contapagar 
LEFT JOIN profissional ON contapagar.profissional_id = profissional.profissional_id 
LEFT JOIN paciente ON contapagar.paciente_id = paciente.paciente_id 
INNER JOIN status_parcela ON contapagar.statusparcela_id = status_parcela.statusparcela_id 
INNER JOIN forma_pagamento ON contapagar.formapgto_id = forma_pagamento.formapgto_id 
INNER JOIN entidade ON contapagar.entidade_id = entidade.entidade_id 
INNER JOIN formapgto_bfinanceiro ON contapagar.formapgtobfin_id = formapgto_bfinanceiro.formapgtobfin_id 

WHERE 
****contapagar.entidade_id= '1' ** // SE EU NÃO TIVER entidade_id selecionado como faço pra retornar todos? **
AND contapagar.planoconta_id= '1' 
AND contapagar.statusparcela_id= '2' 
AND contapagar.contapagar_data between '2023-09-08' AND '2023-09-08' 
ORDER BY `contapagar`.`contapagar_id` ASC
```

Tentado com valores nulos, ALL

Comment: ou caso eu não tenha um valor selecionado das Cláusula, gostaria que fossem todos.

Comment: 1) o que seria "se eu não selecionar um determinado campo" 2) informe o SGBD (Banco de Dados) em questão.

Comment: tentei fazer um comentário na pergunta, mas a idéia é " Caso eu não envie nenhum valor ele  ele iguinorar essa condição. AND contapagar.planoconta_id= '1'.

Answer (score -2):

Para retornar todos os registros quando o campo `contapagar.entidade_id` não for especificado (ou seja, quando for nulo ou vazio), você pode usar a cláusula `OR` na sua consulta SQL para tratar esse caso. Aqui está a consulta modificada:

```sql
SELECT 
  contapagar.*, 
  profissional.profissional_descricao, 
  paciente.paciente_descricao, 
  status_parcela.statusparcela_descricao, 
  forma_pagamento.formapgto_descricao, 
  entidade.entidade_descricao, 
  formapgto_bfinanceiro.formapgtobfin_descricao 
FROM contapagar 
LEFT JOIN profissional ON contapagar.profissional_id = profissional.profissional_id 
LEFT JOIN paciente ON contapagar.paciente_id = paciente.paciente_id 
INNER JOIN status_parcela ON contapagar.statusparcela_id = status_parcela.statusparcela_id 
INNER JOIN forma_pagamento ON contapagar.formapgto_id = forma_pagamento.formapgto_id 
INNER JOIN entidade ON contapagar.entidade_id = entidade.entidade_id 
INNER JOIN formapgto_bfinanceiro ON contapagar.formapgtobfin_id = formapgto_bfinanceiro.formapgtobfin_id 
WHERE 
  (contapagar.entidade_id = '1' OR contapagar.entidade_id IS NULL OR contapagar.entidade_id = '') 
  AND contapagar.planoconta_id = '1' 
  AND contapagar.statusparcela_id = '2' 
  AND contapagar.contapagar_data BETWEEN '2023-09-08' AND '2023-09-08' 
ORDER BY `contapagar`.`contapagar_id` ASC;
```

Nesta consulta, usei a cláusula `OR` para verificar se `contapagar.entidade_id` é igual a '1' OU se é nulo OU se é uma string vazia (''). Isso garantirá que a consulta retorne todos os registros quando `contapagar.entidade_id` não estiver especificado. Certifique-se de que a comparação `contapagar.entidade_id IS NULL` seja feita quando o campo estiver nulo e `contapagar.entidade_id = ''` quando estiver vazio.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo, não fiquei atento as condições, mas desde já deu tudo certo, muito obrigado.